# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given & mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ive searched on here and various other places and I just cannot find the answer to solve this problem. I just bought new hosting and am trying to move my sites. I am getting the error below.

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in
/home4/purefic/public_html/demo/mytcg/settings.php on line 230

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
/home4/purefic/public_html/demo/mytcg/settings.php on line 231
DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR
```

And this is the coding I have on my settings page (originally working just fine on my old host I had everything as mysql and not mysqli like my research seemed to tell me to change to but as you can see it didnt work)

```
$users = array($user => md5($pass));
$salt = substr(md5(date("F")), 8);

$connect = mysqli_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password")
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error() );
mysqli_select_db("$db_database" , $connect)
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error() );

function CleanUp($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    return $data;
    }

function escape_sql($sql) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $sql = stripslashes($sql);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: How is the error not clear enough? It gives a file name, a line number, it even says what it expects so you should know what to look for.

Comment: `$db_database` is not defined. You don't need to quote variables. Per the manual `bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )` -http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php I'd guess your parameters are inverted, Your error function then is missing the link as well.

Comment: It appears as though you have given a string instead of mysqli object. Check the value of `"$db_server"` to make sure it is a mysqli object

Comment: The first parameter should be the connection, then the dbname is passed. like `mysqli_select_db( $connect, "dbname" );` Though you could just do `mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`.  Also `mysqli_error()` should take the `$connection` as an argument. The errors are clear, and you should review the signature of the functions you use from the manual, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

Comment: Not an exact dup, but explains it and shows how to use the error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you no need to have "" for your DB connection because you pass it as a variable

Second thing is In MYSQLI always Pass `$connection` with your Connection.

And for a mysqli_error pass $connection to let server know you are looking for error in Database Connection.

Try this.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password)
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error($connect) );
mysqli_select_db($connect, $db_database)
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error($connect) );
```

**Edit**

either way you can try connect your DB As follow

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);

// If no connection than Print error
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
      echo "No Active DB Connection Please check: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home4/purefic/public_html/demo/mytcg/settings.php on line 231
DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR

Comment: now I get the above error after changing to

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect("$db_server", "$db_user", "$db_password")
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error($connect) );
mysqli_select_db($connect, $db_database)
    or die( DATABASE_CONNECT_ERROR . mysqli_error($connect) );

Comment: Please check edit that may help you